# Tensorflow is not running on miniconda and jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, miniconda

I have installed tensorflow using pip install, but it does not run.

When trying to run it, I receive the following error message:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Please help me to run tensorflow.

Comment: At the end of the full error it will say something like "See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help." Please follow this

Comment: I had installed TF using pip, and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall tensorflow, then reinstall it using conda. Conda will install tensorflow 2.1.0, cuda toolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.6.5. Pip does not install the toolkit or cudnn and you have to download these and change your environment path variable to  point to the directories where they are stored. If you want to install tensorflow 2.2 first install tensorflow 2.1.0 with conda then use pip to install tensorflow 2.2 using pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0. Tensorflow 2.2 is compatible with the toolkit and cudnn versions installed by 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip install tensorflow` instead of conda. Tensorflow works fine for me. But I haven't tried conda yet for installing tensorflow.

Comment: If using `conda`, one should avoid installing packages with `pip` as that can lead to unstable environments.

Comment: ohh, I see...thanks buddy, got to know something new